# SCIM pagination in WSO2 IS 4.6

Tags: pagination, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I am using **WSO2 IS 4.6** .I have listed all the users in **wso2 IS** with SCIM endpoint, But i couldn't list the users with pagination query parameters.Following is the culr command that i used to do this.

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin https://example.com/wso2/scim/Users?startIndex=1&count=2
```

any suggestion ??

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented yet (WSO2IS 5.0.0). WSo2IS only support to filter User.

```
url -v -k --user admin:admin https://example.com/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userNameEqaruna
```